# How can I control the font size of sequence logos?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have many sequence logos, which I plot using `ggplot2` and `ggseqlogo`. The vertical axis remains constant, but the horizontal axis is differing for each plot.

I am not aware how I can create sequence logos with identical width for each letter. I tried to manually adjust the letter width using `stack_width` for varying length of my sequence. Unfortunately, that leads to a gap between the individual letters.

How can I achieve identical letter sizes for plots with varying sequence length without introducing a gap between the letters?

Below an example of the issue I am facing:

```
# "R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)"
# "x86_64-w64-mingw32"
# library(ggplot2)
# library(ggseqlogo)

AA_alphabet <- c('R','H','K','D','E','S','Y','T','N','Q','C','G','P','W','A','V','I','L','M','F')

AA1 = c('RHKDES', 'RHKDES', 'RHKDGP', 'RHKDGP', 'TNQCGP')
ggplot() + geom_logo(AA1, method='p', seq_type='other', namespace=AA_alphabet)+theme_logo()

AA2 = c('RH', 'RH', 'RH', 'TN', 'TN')
ggplot() + geom_logo(AA2, method='p', seq_type='other', namespace=AA_alphabet)+theme_logo()

# control for sequence length:
ggplot() + geom_logo(AA2, method='p',seq_type='other', namespace=AA_alphabet,stack_width = 0.2) + theme_logo()
```

Comment: There is no way to do this as far as I'm concerned, nor does it make any sense to. If you are trying to make positions comparable across different logos, they would have to be the same width.

Comment: @by0 : Thanks for looking into that. I am looking at sites under selection across a dataset consisting of many species. I would like to visualise the variation of AA at sites under selection for my genes of interest using logos. However, the number the number of sites is variable for each gene. For example, having large letters for genes with only two sites under selection is visually not appealing, which is why I stumbled upon this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, how about something like this?

```
require(gridExtra)
AA_alphabet <- c('R','H','K','D','E','S','Y','T','N','Q','C','G','P','W','A','V','I','L','M','F')

AA1 = c('RHKDES', 'RHKDES', 'RHKDGP', 'RHKDGP', 'TNQCGP')
AA2 = c('RH', 'RH', 'RH', 'TN', 'TN')

p1 = ggplot() + geom_logo(AA1, method='p', seq_type='other', namespace=AA_alphabet)+theme_logo()
p2 = ggplot() + geom_logo(AA2, method='p', seq_type='other', namespace=AA_alphabet)+theme_logo()

p3 = grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=1)
print(p3)
```

You can add as many plots as you want to `grid.arrange`, as well as adjust the layout of rows and columns using `ncol` and `nrow` parameters.

Comment: That does the trick -thanks! I haven't considered plotting more than one logo at the time. For cases with only few letter in the logo that will take care of the wasted space.